# How to be healthy in irregular schedule?

Tags: health

I am a high school student, and from few days my regular schedule is disturbed. Means sometimes i need to wake up early while some time I sleep  more than I need.That has affected directly to my physical health.

I will not able to follow any schedule for a month as my exams are coming. So can I be physically healthy in my irregular schedule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am in the same situation actually as a high school student. I wake up at 4:30 in the morning sometimes to get to school and don't get home until 6 just to start my homework. I certainly find that eating healthier is a must. I know it is easy to succumb to the temptation of a bag of chips or a soda on the way home from school just to get some food into you, but grab an apple or a banana instead. If workouts are not going to be possible, then watch what you eat. Even for half an hour find a way to run or bike for a little while. Not only does it help with your physical fitness, it also helps you mentally and keeps you focused and relieves stress. THe gym I usually go to is open late so I will usually study from 7:00-9:00 then go to the gym until 10, returning home to study for another hour. If a gym isn't an option or you just don't have time, there are plenty of at home workouts you can do before or after school to take a  break from the books. This is one of my personal favorite at home workouts:
http://www.muscleandfitness.com/workouts/workout-routines/home-work-no-equipment-home-workout

Comment: @Freddy Glad to help